# SSH in bash mode

Tags: python, ssh

I am new to python. I am trying to enter two commands in my script.

1) script filename.txt
2) ssh xyz@xyz.com

My script stops after the 1st command in executed. When I exit out of bash the 2nd command is execute. I tried 2 different scripts both have the same issue.

## 1) Script-1

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call
from datetime import datetime

call (["script","{}.txt".format(str(datetime.now()))])

echo "ssh xyz@xyz.com"
```

## 2) Script-2

```
call (["script","{}.txt".format(str(datetime.now()))])

def subprocess_cmd(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    proc_stdout = process.communicate()[0].strip()
    print proc_stdout

subprocess_cmd('ssh ssh xyz@xyz.com')
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this will work the way you expect.  In Script-1, the first line starts the `script` executable, and waits for it to finish.  The trouble is, `script` stays running, and spawns a subshell of its own.  Then, when that subshell finishes, `script` itself will also end, and the echo line (which is not valid Python) would run and cause an error.  Script-2 looks more promising, but `call` still waits for `script` to finish.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Is there any better way to have this done?. The requirement is to have the terminal outputs saved to a files.

Comment: If it's possible to know the command ahead of time, you could do something like `script -c "command" filename.txt`.  Otherwise, something like https://pypi.org/project/pyexpect/ may be a good option.

Comment: Oops, I meant https://pypi.org/project/pexpect/, not pyexpect.